# Powershell Regex matches leading and trailing spaces

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to match with Powershell -replace all $test occurrences that are not quoted (line 3, 4, 6, 7 in the sample below)

```
1) '$test'
2) test
3) $test
4) foo $test bar
5) foo '$test' bar
6) foo "$test" foo
7) "$test"
```

I used the regexp below

```
'[^\'']\$test[^\'']'
```

but this matches the space too, for example in the line 4, causing the replace to trim them.

How can I match exactly $test when not embedded in single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex to match $test in the lines 3,4,6,7(ie, `$test` not enclosed within single quotes)

```
(?<!\')\$test(?!\')
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vU4hH1/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\')\$test` Negative lookahead, which ensures that it won't match the string `$test` present just after to the single quote.
- `(?!\')` And the following character wouldn't be a single quote. Regex engine match the string `$test` only if the both conditions are satisfied.